# Enable HTTP check on External Services Consul

Tags: consul

I want to run HTTP checks on services registered as External Services with consul.So far the check gets registered but is never called.
What am I missing.

```
{
"Datacenter": "dc1", 
"Node": "new",
"Address": .google.com",
"Service": {
    "ID":"re",
    "Service": "search2", 
    "Port": 80
 },
 "Check":{
      "Node":"new",
      "CheckID":"Test",
      "HTTP":"http://www.google",
      "ServiceID":"re"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `Interval` to check service health.You can do it as follows:

For TCP port check:

```
{
 "check": {
"id": "http",
"name": "http TCP on port 80",
"tcp": "localhost:80",
"interval": "10s",
"timeout": "1s"
}
}
```

For HTTP api check:

```
 {
 "check": {
"id": "api",
"name": "HTTP API on port 5000",
"http": "https://localhost:5000/health",
"tls_skip_verify": false,
"method": "POST",
"header": {"x-foo":["bar", "baz"]},
"interval": "10s",
"timeout": "1s"
}
}
```

Comment: This method works fine for services running on local nodes but not for external service.

Comment: hi @deepak: I am windows platform to run the consul. I have tried the similar config which u posted. But the health check never registered. Any idea? My whole config is here:  {
  "service": {
    "id":"somename",
 "name":"nameofthissevice",
    "service": "myservice",
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 62133,
    "enableTagOverride": false,
 "check": {
"id": "somename",
"name": "nameofthissevice",
"http": "http://127.0.0.1:62133/Service1.svc/MyService/PingMe",
"tls_skip_verify": false,
"method": "GET",
"interval": "10s",
"timeout": "1s"
}
  }
}